# AWS Step functions: Is it possible to have optional output values in result selector

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

In AWS step functions is it possible to have something like:

```
  "ProcessOutput": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Result": {
        "username.$": "$.Payload?.username" // optional result
      },
      "End": true
    }
```

where `username.$` is optional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Step Functions [path syntax](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-paths.html) does not support optional paths.  The Step Functions execution will fail if `$.Payload.username` is not defined.

Note that in any case, the [Pass](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-pass-state.html) state's `Result` key only accepts static values, not JSONPath references.  The `Parameters` field accepts path substitutions, but just not optional ones.

What alternatives do you have to handle an optional field?  One option is a Lambda task.  A second option is a [Choice](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/amazon-states-language-choice-state.html) state with an `IsPresent` conditional check on the optional field.  If the field is not present, set a default or otherwise handle the case.